# Column's children must not contain any null values, but null value was found at index 0

Tags: ios, flutter, webview

I'm developing a Flutter app, and I am trying to create a InAppWebView. Everything is working well on Android, but on iOS i got an error:

*"Column's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 0".*

I already hit flutter clean, flutter build ios, and clean xcode. But still got this error.

Any help is appreciated

Here is my code:

```
child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("voucherweb")),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              progress == null ? Container() : (progress != 1.0)
              ? LinearProgressIndicator(
                  value: progress,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black))
              : null,
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: InAppWebView(
                  initialUrl: "https://voucherweb.com",
                  initialHeaders: {},
                  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true),
                  ),
                  shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, request) async {
                    var url = request.url;
                    var uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    if (request.url.startsWith("https://wa.me/")) {
                      final newString =
                          url.replaceAll("https://wa.me/", "");
                      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                        FlutterOpenWhatsapp.sendSingleMessage(
                            newString, "Halo, gan. Mau order voucher : ");
                        return ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingAction.CANCEL;
                      }
                    }
                    return ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingAction.ALLOW;
                  },
                  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                    webView = controller;
                  },
                  onLoadStart:
                      (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
                  onLoadStop:
                      (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
                  onProgressChanged:
                      (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.progress = progress / 100;
                    });
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ]))));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting one of the `Column's` child to `null`, consider using a `SizedBox()` or a `Container()` instead:

I added an example using your code:

```
child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("voucherweb")),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              progress == null ? Container() : (progress != 1.0)
              ? LinearProgressIndicator(
                  value: progress,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black))
              // new line
              : SizedBox(),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: InAppWebView(
                  initialUrl: "https://voucherweb.com",
                  initialHeaders: {},
                  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true),
                  ),
                  shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, request) async {
                    var url = request.url;
                    var uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    if (request.url.startsWith("https://wa.me/")) {
                      final newString =
                          url.replaceAll("https://wa.me/", "");
                      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                        FlutterOpenWhatsapp.sendSingleMessage(
                            newString, "Halo, gan. Mau order voucher : ");
                        return ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingAction.CANCEL;
                      }
                    }
                    return ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingAction.ALLOW;
                  },
                  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                    webView = controller;
                  },
                  onLoadStart:
                      (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
                  onLoadStop:
                      (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
                  onProgressChanged:
                      (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.progress = progress / 100;
                    });
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ]))));
```

Comment: i already add : SizedBox(), but got white screen while running. Any suggest?

Comment: NSAppTransportSecurity tag already added on my plist.

Comment: Can you try running on android if you still get the error `"Column's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 0".`

Comment: yes, everything is fine on Android, Webview working well, load the website with no issue. But after i add SizedBox(), on iOS got white screen

Comment: my problem solved, i just add ```<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <true/>``` on plist, and white screen is gone. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
progress == null ? Container() : (progress != 1.0)
? LinearProgressIndicator(
value: progress,
backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black))
: Container(),
```

Please use this code null is not widget that's why you are getting this error.